# What are the different types of degenerate conics and other algebraic curves?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, conic-sections, curves, algebraic-curves

What are the different types of degenerate conics and other algebraic curves?

Consider $$Ax^2 + 2Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0.$$

This can fail to be a standard conic in multiple ways:

1. $A = B = C = 0$.  In this case, the degree is 1, and the curve isn't a conic at all.  This is not considered degenerate.
2. $A > 0, B = 0, C > 0, F < 0$.  This is an imaginary ellipse, also not considered degenerate.
3. $A > 0, B = 0, C > 0, F = 0$.  This is degenerate, because it can be factored (?).

Is that correct? "Degenerate" proper is when the polynomial can be factored.  If it's not degenerate, and is of the full degree, it can still not correspond to the standard geometric curve if (but only if) it's imaginary?

Comment: What parts of this aren't answered by typical references, like [the wikipedia page on degenerate conics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic)?

Comment: @HankScorpio I went through the wikipedia pages and other references, and incorporated what I believe I deduced into the OP (that's indeed how I wrote the OP).  However, given that this material is advanced and sometimes (seemingly?) contradictory, I assembled what I believe to be true into the post above, with the hopes that clarification, confirmation, or revision would be helpful both to me and to others attempting to learn this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are assigning signs to the coefficients, you seem to be dealing with real algebraic curves.  In such case, the conic $x^2+y^2+1=0$, i.e., the empty set, will certainly be considered degenerate, and the rule of thumb is that a real conic is nondegenerate iff it is an ellipse, parabola, or hyperbola, or equivalently if it can be represented by an intersection in $\mathbb R^3$ of a standard cone and a plane not passing through the origin.  Of course if you want to complexify the situation, or consider the projectivized curve, the situation will be different as mentioned in the other *answer*.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to describe a degenerate conic is that it's a conic which factors as a product of two lines over an *algebraically closed field*. Your classification does not include any reference to that, and it causes you to miss things like $x^2+y^2$ which gives you a single point over $\Bbb R$ which really ought to be considered degenerate.

Your list of conditions which correspond to degeneracies is not complete (for instance, there are degenerate conics which do not satisfy $A>0,B=0,C>0,F=0$ like $x^2+xy=x(x+y)$; there are imaginary ellipses with nonzero $B$; etc.). The best way to check whether a conic is degenerate or not is to compute a determinant, as described on the wikipedia page: the conic $Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2+2Dx+2Ey+F=0$ is degenerate iff $$\det \begin{pmatrix} A & B & D \\ B & C & E \\ D & E & F \end{pmatrix} = 0.$$ This is because this matrix condition corresponds to a singular point on the projective closure of your conic over an algebraically closed field, and this happens iff your conic decomposes as a union of two lines (this may require you to learn a bit more algebraic geometry to fully understand this).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not familiar with the details of [algebraically closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field).  What is the salient property as used here? Re "the best way to check whether a conic is degenerate or not is to compute a determinant", I'm not trying to check particular functions, but to understand the classification in general (specifically the relationship between the geometric constructions and the algebraic equations).

Comment: The picture over $\Bbb R$ is necessarily incomplete - you can't "see" everything. For instance, $xy$ and $x^2+y^2=(x+iy)(x-iy)$ are both two lines that meet at 0, but you can only see one point on the second pair because they're complex lines, not real lines. The reason I mentioned the determinant was that you seemed to want a full classification, and that's what this gives you - no messing around with an incomplete list of conditions and inequalities, just "is this determinant 0, yes or no". And this determinant relates the geometry to the algebra, so I don't know why you're complaining.

Comment: Clarification $\neq$ complaining.